# How to get the categories child category list per store in magento2 rest api

Tags: magento2, category, api, rest-api, category-tree

I need to retrieve categories and child-category list per store. I have two store have store code grocery and fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Method :GET 
  URL: http://yourdomain/index.php/rest/store-code/V1/categories \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer token--string--' \
```

for store grocery call api

```
Method :GET 
  URL: http://yourdomain/index.php/rest/grocery/V1/categories \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer token--string--' \
```

for store fruit call api

```
Method :GET 
  URL: http://yourdomain/index.php/rest/fruit/V1/categories \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer token--string--' \
```